# Is it common for XML tags to be missing the beginning tag?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm using the python module XMl ElementTree to parse a bunch of XML files. Normally a tag containing text will be written as,

```
<Tag>some text is here</Tag>
```

and if there is no text associated with the tag we'll have,

```
<Tag></Tag>
```

but some of my files only have,

```
<Tag/>
```

Is this common with XMLs or am I looking at a poorly constructed file?

Comment: is it </Tag> or <Tag/> that you are seeing for tags with not ext associated?

Comment: A tag like `<Tag/>` is perfectly valid.  This is simply an empty self-closing tag.  A stand alone tag like `</Tag>` is not valid xml.  This would be a closing tag with no corresponding opening tag.  If you are seeing that, something is going wrong with the source of your file - it is generating invalid xml, and you will not be able to parse it with any xml processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tag like `<tag/>` is an **empty-element tag** (also called a self-closing tag), which is shorthand for `<tag></tag>`: both represent an empty element.

Quoted from the [W3C Recommendation on XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-eetag):

> [Definition: An element with no content is said to be **empty**.]
> The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag.
> [Definition: An **empty-element tag** takes a special form:]
>
> ***Tags for Empty Elements***
>
> [44] *EmptyElemTag* ::= `<` Name (S Attribute)* S? `/>`
>
> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword `EMPTY`. For interoperability, the empty-element tag SHOULD[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) be used, and SHOULD only be used, for elements which are declared `EMPTY`.
>
> Examples of empty elements:
>
> ```
> <IMG align="left"
>      src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/WWW/w3c_home" />
> <br></br>
> <br/>
> ```

### A word about non-XML (HTML) *void* elements

The above should not be confused with the **non-XML** concept of *void elements* in HTML, which may be written like `<tag/>` as well.

Quoted from [W3C HTML Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html) (I highlighted point 5):

> A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances.
>
> **start tags** consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> 1. A `<` character.
> 2. The element’s tag name.
> 3. Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by one or more space characters.
> 4. Optionally, one or more space characters.
> 5. **Optionally, a `/` character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.**
> 6. A `>` character.
>
> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

So although one can have `<br/>` in a non-XML HTML document, it does not completely represent the same concept as in XML. It is not a *self-closing* tag, but a syntactic alternative for `<br>`, a *void* element, which is a concept foreign to XML.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no opening tag for a closing tag the document is not a valid Xml. It's OK to have a tag without a value `<Tag />` - which is an equivalent to `<Tag></Tag>` but it is not valid to have a closing tag without a corresponding opening tag. Elements also have to be correctly nested.

Answer (score 3):

A common thing is

```
<tag/>
```

, which is an equivalent of

```
<tag></tag>
```

, useful when there is no inner content.
For example, you can see in html :

```
<img src="foo.png"/>
```

But

```
</tag>
```

alone is not valid in standard contexts.